Flow is not getting triggered
I have configured a webhook URL in outbound messages and have set  a flow for Opportunity update with action as configured outbound message.
The issue I am facing is the trigger frequently fails to happen, i.e. if I update the stage for 10 times, only 2 or 3 times it is getting triggered.


Make sure that the flow entry criteria are met every time you update the stage. Also, Check this Track the Delivery Status of an Outbound Message

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  If you are able to replicate the issue on-demand, you should capture a debug log in Setup > Debug Logs.
